# why request.body is empty?

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

I try to get data from a user:

```
class EchoWebSocket(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):

def open(self):
    print("WebSocket opened")

def on_message(self, message):
    nom = self.get_argument("nom") # this will return an error, because nom is not found
    # I then tried to retrieve the result of the body,
    print(self.request.body) # nothing to show!

def on_close(self):
    print("WebSocket closed")
```

client side:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#frm").on("submit", function(e){
    var formdata = $("#frm").serialize()
    console.log(formdata) // gives _xsrf=2%7C0fc414f0%7Cf5e0bd645c867be5879aa239b5ce0dfe%7C1456505450&nom=sdfsdf
    var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000/websocket");
    ws.onopen = function() {
       ws.send(formdata);
    };
    ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
       alert(evt.data);
    };
    e.preventDefault();
  })
})
</script>

<form action="/websocket" method="post" id="frm">
  {% raw xsrf_form_html() %}
  <input type="text" name="nom" autofocus>
  <button class="ui primary button">Envoyer</button>
</form>
```

I have tried a simple ajax way, and got:

```
class AjaxHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        print self.request.body
        #gives: _xsrf=2%7C0d466237%7Cf762cba35e040d228518d4feb74c7b39%7C1456505450&nom=hello+there
```

My question: How to get the user input using websocket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A websocket message is not a new HTTP request. self.request (and related methods like self.get_argument()) refer to the HTTP request that opened the websocket and do not change when new messages arrive. Instead, the only thing you get with a websocket message is the `message` argument to on_message(). This contains the data that was sent by the javascript, and you must parse it yourself.

```
def on_message(self, message):
    args = {}
    tornado.httputil.parse_body_arguments("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", message, args, {})
    print(args["nom"][0])
```

You may want to use JSON instead of form encoding for this; it is generally easier to work with when you don't need backwards-compatibility with plain HTML form submission.

Comment: ah! thank you Ben, that worked like a charm, indeed, I found the notice you made in the docs about `get/post` but dident knew how to pass the argument when using websocket.

Comment: why did you used the empty dict? (it is available twice in the parse_body_arguments)

Comment: See the docs for parse_body_arguments. It takes two dicts and fills them in. The first is used for arguments and the second is for files. You're not sending any files here so I just passed an empty throw-away dict for that, but the args dict is bound to a local variable.